# File Version Info give me wrong build part

Tags: c#

My file.exe File version is : 0.0.20130211.0
but in FileBuildPart it shows me : 10659

what should i do for that?
why it give me wrong build part?

Comment: Write your code here..

Answer (score 2):

FileBuildPart is a 32-bit value.

The LS 32-bits of 20130211 = 0x13329A3 are 0x29A3 = 10659